# Referencing a cell within an Excel Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The first column of my Excel table will change its name (based on another cell).
In the second column, I need to perform a lookup using the first column.

| Cost Centre Code | Cost Centre Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | =XLOOKUP([@[Cost Centre Code]],OtherTable[Codes],OtherTable[Name] |
| ABC555 | =XLOOKUP([@[Cost Centre Code]],OtherTable[Codes],OtherTable[Name] |

This works fine when the lookup column value won't change. But my "Cost Centre Code" could change and be called "Project Code". I need to find a way for my `[@[Cost Centre Code]]` to become `[@[Project Code]]`.

I was thinking about `INDIRECT()` and have tried `INDIRECT("[@["&XLOOKUP(formula goes here)&"]]")` but am receiving a #REF! error. And I've tried to use the "Evaluate Formula" function to no avail. The formula looks perfect until `INDIRECT("[@[Project Code]]")`, but when the INDIRECT is removed, the correct named range doesn't take hold.

Is anyone aware of the fix to get `INDIRECT()` to be accepted, or is there another formula which can be used?

Comment: Is this the only column that could change name? Perhaps you could lookup a non-dynamic column and then use `OFFSET`?

Comment: @SpencerBarnes Unless I've misunderstood, that doesn't work either. I still need to perform a lookup on the entry in "Cost Centre Code" (or whatever it's called). So I still need to reference ```[@[Cost Centre Code]]``` (or whatever it's called). I've tried ```OFFSET``` to name the cell ```"[@[Cost Centre Code]]"``` but can't find a way to remove the ```"``` without ```INDIRECT``` at which point I'm in the same boat as in my example. If I've misunderstood, can you elaborate?

Comment: In the cell, when you change `Cost Centre Code` to `Project Code`, the reference changes automatically (on its own) in the formulas (to work properly).

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing, @VBasic2008. My Table is being generated from Jet (SQL), so the column headers can be renamed but the formulae which links to this column isn't as easily updated

Comment: What happens If you 'hardcode' it: `=XLOOKUP(A2,OtherTable[Codes],OtherTable[Name])` (use the appropriate cell address instead of `A2`)?

Comment: Thanks, both, for your help with this. I've managed to get it to work by building the formula this way: ```XLOOKUP(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)),OtherTable[Codes],OtherTable[Name])``` which has worked a treat.

Comment: If the Table **Name** stays the same, you could use the non-volatile `=INDEX(TableA,1,1)` to refer to the first cell of data in the first column, or `=INDEX(TableA,0,1)` to refer to the first column of data